# A PYTHONSTARTUP file for a specific directory

Tags: python

I've heard about the PYTHONSTARTUP file as a way to automatically load specified modules and other code when starting python.  But PYTHONSTARTUP is a global thing, for all instances of python.  Is there such a thing as PYTHONSTARTUP that I can place in a specific directory and runs only when I start python in that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just export the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable before starting up each project.

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/myproject/.pystartup
python ~/myproject/start.py

export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/myotherproject/.pystartup
python ~/myotherproject/start.py
```

Or you could have a simple bash file that contains the environment and the python command you wish to run.

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename: workon.sh
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/myproject/.pystartup
python ~/myproject/start.py
```

Then:

```
./workon.sh
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I made a file called "python" in my project directory which does the `export` and then runs python.  So just typing `python` at the cmd gives me regular old python.  But typing `./python` gives me my modules.  Thanks!

Comment: @J-bob If you have project directories anyway, you're really just faking up your own virtualenv. Just use the standard tool, and benefit from the full set of feautures.

Comment: @Marcin, thanks for the advice.  I admit that I never really understood what virtualenv does.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) is an environment variable, you can set it on a per-instance basis.

In sh-compatible shells, you can set a variable for the duration of a single process with

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/you/special.py python arguments ...
```

To set it permanently for all Python instances, put something like

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/you/regular.py
export PYTHONSTARTUP
```

in your shell's startup file.

You can override the global default for the current shell:

```
bash$ PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/you/another.py
```

(and `export PYTHONSTARTUP` if it's not already exported) or for individual processes as per the first example.

On Windows and in Csh-compatible shells, the details of the syntax will be different, but the concept is by and large the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some code in the python startup-file, which only executes depending on your current working directory.

Adding the snippet below in `.python` prints hello if python is started from `/home/myuser/mydir`.

```
import os

if os.getcwd()=="/home/myuser/mydir":
     print "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want to use `virtualenv`. It's a tool for creating isolated python environments with hooks for individual settings. Just put them in the `bin/activate` of your virtualenv.