# Can someone tell me the purpose of PYTHONSTARTUP?

Tags: python

i have heard this is an environment variable but Can someone tell me the purpose of PYTHONSTARTUP?

Comment: Please, visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534230/a-pythonstartup-file-for-a-specific-directory

Comment: RTFM. No, really, it's in the manpage. Also easy to locate on the web. Stop being lazy!

Answer (score 6):

**PYTHONSTARTUP** is an environment variable you will define specifying the location of the path to a python file. 
This python script will be run by python before starting the python interactive mode (interpreter). You can use it for various enhancements like preloading modules, setting colors. ([Here](http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2014-03-21-Enhancing-the-Python-interpreter-with-a-start-up-script.html)) is a helpful post.

Developers use something called dotfiles to enhance the bash environment. Lookup github for sample dotfile scripts which enhances the bash. You can use it with a similar state of mind. [Here](https://github.com/jezdez/python-startup) is a github startup script.