# Run python script at python startup

Tags: python, executable

I have a python executable called `python.exe` and and a launcher `python-launcher.exe` that preliminary sets environment variables before launching `python.exe`.

If I run:

```
python-launcher.exe -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

I get `python.exe` printed. But the problem is that I need it to be `python-launcher.exe`.

I thought maybe I could write a script that modifies executable `import sys; sys.executable="python-launcher.exe"` and that is called everytime python is launched?

P.S. I cannot modify or recompile `python-launcher.exe` but I have an opportunity to set environment variables in `.ini` config file.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe you want to set `PYTHONSTARTUP` to get a script run before your main one... https://stackoverflow.com/a/29690425/2836621

Comment: @Mark Setchell thank you. That almost worked. Seems that `PYTHONSTARTUP` executes script only when interactive mode started. Thus when doing `python-launcher.exe -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` unfortunately it has no effect.